# Solving $\sinh z = 2i$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

This is my attempt at the question (I stopped early because it did not work out...)
$$\sinh z = 2i \\ e^{iz} - e^{-iz} = 4i \\ e^{2iz} - 4ie^{iz} - 1 = 0 $$
solving the quadratic gives
$$e^{iz} = i(2\pm \sqrt{3})$$
I stop here to check:
$$\sinh z = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2}= \frac{i(2\pm\sqrt{3}) + i(2\pm \sqrt{3})}{2}= i(2\pm \sqrt{3}) \neq 2i...$$

I'm not sure if I'm doing something really wrong… I've redone this a few times and I can't see it.

Comment: If $e^{iz}=i(2+\sqrt3)$ then $e^{-iz}=-i(2-\sqrt3)$.

Comment: Also, you actually want to solve $e^z-e^{-z}=4i$.

Comment: Ah right for I solved $i\sinh z = 4i$ instead. But isn't $e^{iz} = i(2+\sqrt{3}) = 2i + i\sqrt{3}$ so $e^{-iz} = \overline{2i + i\sqrt{3}} = -2i - i\sqrt{3} = -i(2+\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: Really, $e^{iz}$ and $e^{-iz}$ should multiply to $1$.

Comment: Ah right so yours should be correct; but how come if I set $e^{iz} = i(2+\sqrt{3})$, I can't take the conjugate of both sides to give $\overline{e^{iz}} = e^{-iz} = -i(2+\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: Oh it's because $\overline{e^{iz} = e^{-i \overline{z}}$?

Comment: $$\sinh z = \frac{e^{z} - e^{-z}}{2}\ne \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2}$$

Comment: `Solve[Sinh[z] == 2 I, z]` $\left\{\left\{z\to \text{ConditionalExpression}\left[2 i \pi  c_1+i \pi -i \sin ^{-1}(2),c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\right]\right\},\left\{z\to \text{ConditionalExpression}\left[2 i \pi  c_1+i \sin ^{-1}(2),c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\right]\right\}\right\}$

Answer (score 2):

Use $\sinh^{-1} w = \ln(w+\sqrt{1+w^2})$ to evaluate

$$z = \sinh^{-1} 2i=\ln(2i+\sqrt{1-4})=\ln(2i\pm i\sqrt3)=\ln i + \ln(2\pm\sqrt3)$$

Since $\ln i = \ln e^{i\frac\pi2 + i2n\pi} = i\frac\pi2 + i2n\pi$, the complete set of solutions are

$$z = i\frac\pi2 + i2n\pi + \ln(2\pm\sqrt3)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sinh z=2i$$
$$e^z-e^{-z}=4i$$
$$(e^z+2i-i\sqrt{3})(e^z+2i+i\sqrt{3})=0$$
$$z=(2n\pi+\arg i(-2\pm\sqrt3))i+log|i(-2\pm\sqrt3)|$$
$$z=(2n\pi+\pi/2+0)i+log|i|+log|(-2\pm\sqrt3)|$$
$$z=(2n+1/2)i\pi+log|-2\pm\sqrt3|$$

Answer (score -3):

Actually, correct version of the last expression is

$$ \sinh(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2}=\frac{i(2\pm\sqrt{3})+i(2\mp\sqrt{3})}{2}=2i $$

Use $z=(2+\sqrt{3})i$ or $z=(2-\sqrt{3})i $ uniformly in the all part of expression